# Need to Extract String from Result of awk Command and Copy to Output File

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I want to extract strings from a terraform.tfstate file.

I am running the following ack command:
...

```
awk '/nifi1a/{x=1}x&&/private_ip/{print;exit}' terraform.tfstate
```

Running this command results in:

```
"private_ip": "10.42.229.45",
```

I would like to extract the string between the second set of double quotes i.e., `10.42.229.45` and copy this to an out put file.

Can someone provide guidance/recommendations on how to do this?

Comment: I would like the second command to act on the resultant string that results from running the awk command indicated in the question.

Comment: You want to extract **and** copy to a file. The second part (copy the output to a file) seems quite trivial, which makes me wonder: Don't you know how to write something to a file in Linux (for instance, using redirection - `> file`)? Because that seems like a different question - "how to write something to a file". But if you do know how to use redirection, why are you asking? Why is it important that the answer also shows how to write the output to a file? Is there anything you need in particular that cannot be fulfilled using a regular redirection?

Comment: Is `terraform.tfstate` a JSON file? if so, it would likely be simpler and more robust to use a JSON tool such as `jq`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chances are all you need is:

```
awk -F'"' '/nifi1a/{f=1} f && /private_ip/{print $4; exit}' terraform.tfstate
```

but without sample input that's just a guess and the original part of the code may not be optimal, there may be some better (more concise, portable, robust, etc.) way to do what you want.

Don't assume people reading your questions will know what a "a terraform.tfstate file" or any other input format is, always show us concise, testable sample input and expected output so we can best help you.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `print` you can `split` the string and print only the required part:

```
awk '/nifi1a/{x=1}x&&/private_ip/{split($0,a,"\""); print a[4];exit}' terraform.tfstate
```

If you want to create second command to work on result you can use command:

```
awk '/nifi1a/{x=1}x&&/private_ip/{print;exit}' terraform.tfstate | awk -F\" '{print $4}'
```

The idea is to use double quote `"` as delimiter and split `$0` in array. And then print only one element of array.

If you want to add hostname the command will be:

```
awk '/nifi1a/{x=1}x&&/private_ip/{split($0,a,"\""); print a[4], "nifi1a";exit}' terraform.tfstate >>/etc/hosts
```